How to load all types of dependency, assembly and Dll in .NET Core code
I get this error whenever I rebuild my code:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
dependencies. Either a required impersonation level was not provided,
or the provided impersonation level is invalid. (Exception from
HRESULT: 0x80070542)

I have added the assembly, dependencies, and also the DLL, but the issue is still not resolved. Please advise on this.

These are the dependencies I found for the pakage Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0 which looks very old. May I know whether you've installed the corresponding .net environment?

Please bear with me, I also want to confirm whether you tried to clean the project and try rebuild? Based on your description, I prefer to think that you are now maintaining an out-of-box application with complete feature, but not working from the beginning, so that I think everything should already configured well. So that my assumption are around the environment and cache.'

I have already installed the latest .NET 8.0.100 version, but it still shows the same error.

Could you please install .Net 5 as well although it's end-of-life now, just for testing purpose.

Have to install specific .Net 5

The issue resolved after installing .Net 5? @AshishMaurya

The issue remains unresolved despite the installation of .NET 5.

Could you pls help confirm whether your project could work well in another computer? If yes, could you please try this .Net repair tool?

Yes, the issue has been resolved. Thank you for your response.

May I know the solution? The repaire tool help resolved the issue?

Yes, the issue has been resolved. Thank you for your response

May I know whether the repaire tool helped resolve the issue?
